# How to deploy laravel application using github action

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, github-actions

I am trying to deploy my laravel application to my server using Github actions for build and test and then deploy via ssh.

I have a master repository that I use for development and then I have a production repo that is attached to actions script.

I tried following [this tutorial](https://laravel-news.com/push-deploy-with-github-actions) for github actions deployment.

My build works fine but at the time of deployment it is not able to find my deployment script i.e server_deploy.sh

here's my main.yml file

```
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ production ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.PUSH_TOKEN }}
    - name: Set up Node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12.x'
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run production
    - name: Commit built assets
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
        git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
        git checkout -B deploy
        git add -f public/
        git commit -m "Build front-end assets"
        git push -f origin deploy
    - name: Deploy to production
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
        host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
        password: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSWORD }}
        script: 'cd /home/admin/web/case4.example.co/public_html/ && ls && sh server_deploy.sh'
```

and here's my server_deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

echo "Deploying application ..."

# Enter maintenance mode
(php artisan down --message 'The app is being (quickly!) updated. Please try again in a minute.') || true
    # Update codebase
    git fetch origin deploy
    git reset --hard origin/deploy

    # Install dependencies based on lock file
    composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

# Exit maintenance mode
php artisan up

echo "Application deployed!"
```

However, when I execute this workflow, it cannot find the server_deploy.sh file.
[image: Deployment error]

I tried `ls` to see if even my repo checks out but it doesn't.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't setup your server according to the tutorial

> Note that the server is always on the deploy branch.

> With all this set up, install your Laravel application into `/var/www/html` and checkout the `deploy` branch. If it doesn’t exist yet, you can do `git checkout production && git checkout -b deploy` to create it.

You have to run this once on your server and checkout the deploy branch that contains the deploy script `server_deploy.sh`

Comment: so should I clone the repository in public_html directory and then check out the deploy branch? I thought it will be created automatically, also won't it become a security concern if I put `.git` directory in public_html?

Comment: You have to setup your server in a way that the `.git` directory isn't served / accessible from the outside.
The deploy script depends on you having a git repository there, because the git commands it uses require an existing checked out repository.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to login first to your server and then upload the `server_deploy.sh` to your root folder; e.g: `/var/www/html`